# Create nav design using tailwind css

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm new in CSS and VueJs so I'm creating a tab panel design + functionality

Currently, I'm using the tailwind CSS plugin

My desire design is this:

[image: desireResult]

Current: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/geringanetor/pen/RwgjLxO)

I can't replicate the desire because I'm missing:

- Space between elements: I try using `flex space-x-10` or `grid grid-gap-20` but it does not work
- Gray at the background: I try it    using `bg-gray-600` inside `<nav>` but
  cause not effect
- Change selected tab on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is change your nav directly in css, with:

```
nav {
    width: max-content; /*This gonna set a fixed width, it is necessary*/
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px; /*increase as much you want to stay like your template, it is the space between the elements in your flex*/
    background: #ccc; /*Just put your color directly*/
    border-radius: 20px; /*Just put your radius*/;
}
```

Comment: Nice!, how can I add space on the text at the start and at the end of the nav, as image I.E : PDF text is not in the rounded gray corner, it has some space at the right and it looks centered

Comment: Well, you can add some padding inside the "<a>", and your PDF should have the same classes of the other tags, get it?

Comment: It is always nice to talk with Jesus o/